# How to legitimately obtain raw keyboard scancode without requiring additional priveleges (OSX)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keyboard, scancodes

In recent releases of OSX, an application is no longer able to access a HID device without being granted additional *Input Monitoring* privileges.

Until now, I had a bunch of code that deals directly with raw scancodes from the HID device.  Partly this is for cross platform purposes (it's not a keylogger, and yes there are other ways).

It seems that Cocoa does not expose raw scancodes whatsoever, seeming to only issue keyDown events using virtual keycodes.

Is there any facility that allows me to obtain raw keyboard scancodes without having to read directly from the HID device? And without requiring *Input Monitoring* permission?